# TinyMCE is removing elements like <title>, <script> from the document loaded onto it

Tags: tinymce

A similar problem was reported here:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=78

My TinyMCE initialization code is as follows:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector : "mceEditor",
            width : "94%%",
            height : "449px",
            theme :"advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,link,unlink,|,undo,redo",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

    theme_advanced_resizing : false,


    //content_css : "css/word.css",
            convert_urls : false,
             extended_valid_elements: 'script[src|title|type],title[dir<ltr?rtl|lang]',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By default TinyMCE only allows editing of the body part of a HTML page, as this is the most common use case. If you want to use it to edit a full HTML page I'd suggest using the fullpage plugin: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:fullpage

Answer (score 1):

Add plugin to TinyMCE plugin option list example: plugins : "fullpage".

Answer (score 0):

You had an error in your tinymce config (height and width need to get set as a value without 'px'). Check [this fiddle out.](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) The element stay there and do not get stripped out (you may verify this using the html/code button).